# Angular 4 select element multiple value and

Tags: html, angular, html-select

I am trying to add a select HTML element with multiple attribute set to it in a normal Angular 4 reactive form.

When checked in Chrome developer console, it shows following HTML:

**Actual:**

```
<select class="form-control ..." formcontrolname="..." id="..." multiple="" name="..." required="" ...>
    <option value="0: 'MBA'" ng-reflect-value="MBA">MBA</option>
    <option value="1: 'MSc'" ng-reflect-value="MSc">MSc</option>
</select>
```

**Expected:**

```
<select class="form-control ..." formcontrolname="..." id="..." multiple="" name="..." required="" ...>
    <option value="MBA" ng-reflect-value="MBA">MBA</option>
    <option value="MSc" ng-reflect-value="MSc">MSc</option>
</select>
```

Why is the `value` and `ng-reflect-value` different.
This is creating problem for me to get selected values, set default values, etc.

This does not happen when `multiple` attribute is removed.

Any idea what is going wrong here. Yes, I have google this issue but couldn't find any solution.

**Edit:**

In Component:

```
//variables
form: FormGroup;
degrees: FormControl;
degree_list = ['MBA', 'MCA', ...];

//through constructor parameters
private _fb = FormBuilder;

//in ngOnInit
this.form = this._fb.group({
    ...
    degrees: this._fb.control('');
    ...
});
```

In Template file:

```
...

<select class="form-control" name="degrees" id="degrees" formControlName="degrees" multiple required>
    <option *ngFor="let degree of degree_list" [value]="degree">{{degree}}</option>
</select>

...
```

Comment: Don't bother inspecting the component with the dev tools. Instead, show us the code you use to create a multiple select input please !

Comment: @trichetriche I have added the code, please check.

Comment: Ok so from what I see, you give your `degrees` a string value, while a select multiple return an array of strings. Maybe you could define it as an empty array instead ?

Comment: Tried that, but no change. Tried using `[(ngModel)]` instead too. The `value` data is set in the same way for empty form itself.

Comment: With ngModel, could make a console log of the value on a `change` event ? This would tell you what exactly the value is

Comment: The `(change)` does not even get fired. Tried setting values by default like `degrees: this._fb.control(['MBA']);` and that does not work either.

Comment: Well if the change event doesn't get fired, you certainly have an issue ! Let me make a stackblitz for you, I'll be back in a while

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you or did you solve this in another way/still having issues? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12074#issuecomment-251475820 you can initialize your formcontrol with an empty array. Also since you are using a reactive form, remove the `required` from your template and instead set the Validator when you build the form:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    degrees: [[''], Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Also notice I removed `this._fb.control` I'm not sure why you are using that :)

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhrz1w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**